# Synonymize and merge [oauth] and [openauth] and [open-authentication]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The following tags are one of the same:

- [oauth](/questions/tagged/oauth) x 5,145
- [openauth](/questions/tagged/openauth) x 22
- [open-authentication](/questions/tagged/open-authentication) x 7

And they should link to the same set of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've completed this.  I didn't create synonyms; 29 questions is not a lot of questions to retag (even less, since there was some overlap), so I retagged them to [oauth](/questions/tagged/oauth).